# Ordering Entity datasource wilth Nulls first

Tags: entity-framework, entitydatasource

I have gridview in which some a column has both alphabets and nulls values coming from database(oracle). But when i perform the sort operation on that column it is sorting the data in ascending with NULL values coming at the last. After some analysis i came to know that oracle by default sorts the data with NULLs at the end.

Is there any way i can override this default behaviour?

I tried by setting orderby property of Entity Data Source like below.

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server" EnableDelete="True" EnableUpdate="True"
            ConnectionString="name=HQADataEntities" DefaultContainerName="HQADataEntities" OrderBy="CASE 
            WHEN it.[GNRC_LKUP_CATEGORY] is null THEN 0 
            else 1      
            END,it.[GNRC_LKUP_CATEGORY]"
            EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EntitySetName="GEN_LOOKUP">
```

But this woking on initial page load, when i perform sort by clicking the grid header it is not performing the sort correctly.